# jquery ui multiple dynamic dialogs

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

So I have like a list of users on a page. each user name is clickable and it displays the user information in the dialog. Right now I'm using a static length for the list.
I would like jquery to see how big the list of users is and apply the code to the list.

Check out the code here:

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true
    };
    $([1, 2, 3, 4]).each(function() {
            var num = this;
            var dlg = $('#dialog-player-' + num).dialog(options);
            $('#player-link-' + num).click(function() {
                    dlg.dialog("open");
                    return false;
            });
    });
```

});

I looked at this page of the documentation: [each](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each)
What I tried is to select all divs in container "div#parent". Like so:

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true
    };
    $("div#parent div").each(function() {
            var num = this;
            var dlg = $('#dialog-player-' + num).dialog(options);
            $('#player-link-' + num).click(function() {
                    dlg.dialog("open");
                    return false;
            });
    });
```

});

But that didn't work. Anybody know of any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed a bug in your code and fixed it for you:

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true
    };
    var num = 1;
    $("div#parent div").each(function() {
            var dlg = $('#dialog-player-' + num).dialog(options);
            $('#player-link-' + num).click(function() {
                    dlg.dialog("open");
                    return false;
            });
            num = num + 1;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true
    };
    $(['George', 'Ralph', 'Carmine', 'Suzy']).each(function(index, val) {
            var num = index;
            var dlg = $('#dialog-player-' + num).dialog(options);
            $('#player-link-' + num).click(function() {
                    dlg.dialog("open");
                    return false;
            });
    });
});
```

You had the right idea the first time. Just use the index supplied by the each function. No need for a separate counter.

Answer (score 0):

look up 'children' in the docs - I think you might need to cycle through the children of the element using each rather than what you have done. e.g.

$("div#parent").children('div').each(function(){etc...})

Comment: Well I tried it, but it didn't work. I also tried using .siblings(), but didn't work either